# Where is .xprofile in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: xorg, configuration, home-directory

The question is in the title. I have seen a few articles and answers talking about configuring .xprofile, file that is supposed to be in my home directory. I have selected "show hidden files" but .xprofile is nowhere to find.
Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default there is no .xprofile file in your home directory unless you create one. The instructions for making an .xprofile file are found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#By_Session_with_.xprofile) under the *How to setup a dual monitor* heading in the Ubuntu Resolution wiki.

> Use your favorite editor to create `~/.xprofile` containing something
>   like:
>
> ```
> xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60
> ```
>
> Now that command will be run every time your start your Xsession. You
>   can force it to run by logging out and logging back in or by executing
>   `~/.xprofile` from your terminal.
>
> Here is an example of my `~/.xprofile`. The `#` are for comments just
>   like you do with shell scripts. The purpose of my setup is sometime
>   have laptop on the left and other times I have my laptop on the right.
>   This makes very simple and easy to change which side you want each
>   monitor to be on. I just added the information on how to set your
>   primary monitor.
>
> ```
> xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60
>
> #Laptop right extra Monitor Left
> #xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1
>
> #Laptop left extra Monitor right
> xrandr --output LVDS1 --left-of VGA1
>
> #This is to set your primary monitor.
>
> #This sets your laptop monitor as your primary monitor. 
> xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary
>
> #This sets your VGA monitor as your primary monitor. 
> #xrandr --output VGA1 --primary
> ```
>
> Some people think it is a disadvantage that this only works for one
>   user, other people think this is an advantage. If you want to be able
>   to use this just copy it over to your profile folder.
>
> **Important Note**: If you just blindly copy some commands from a website, you may see an error message:
>
> ```
> xrandr: cannot find mode 1024×768
> ```
>
> This may be due to some CMS' way of modifying content: xrandr expects
>   the letter x and not the multiplication cross × between horizontal and
>   vertical resolution.
>
> **Incorrect example**:
>
> ```
> xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024×768 --rate 60
> ```
>
> **Corrected example**:
>
> ```
> xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --rate 60
> ```